# Check-in code to TFS 2017 using C# and Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client

Tags: c#, tfs, continuous-integration, tfs-sdk

We have a suite of programs (service plug-ins) which all depend on a complex hierarchy of in-house NuGet packages, these are written in C# and held in TFS 2017 with CI builds to maintain the packages.

I'm wanting to write a utility which will enable me to check-in a change that will then kick off a series of automatic edits, check-ins and builds to update and rebuild the suite automatically.  The alternative is an entire day of check-out/update packages/check-in/merge/check-in, rinse-and-repeat (and, yes, the architecture HAS been optimised as good as possible!).

The automatic dependency determination and editing part is easy but I'm struggling to find any decent documentation and/or examples of code for the getting and checking-in the code using C# and the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client (etc.) - all the examples and doco. I've found so far is either very out of date (2012) or deals with just reading stuff, work items, reports and the like, not updating the code within the repository.

I have one piece of code from a 2010 blog which works but I hesitate to re-purpose it as it's so out of date and uses deprecated APIs.

Can anyone please point me to some decent doco. or examples for checking in programmatically with C# and 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this (with TFS 2017), I do not know if it's you methods you've seen in the blog, anyway I have this excellent works.

- Create a workspace:

  ```
  // Connect to TFS
  TfsTeamProjectCollection _tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsUrl));
  VersionControlServer _sourceControl = (VersionControlServer)_tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
  // Create workspace
  Workspace _workSpace = _sourceControl.CreateWorkspace("test");
  ```
- Add the files to "Pending Changes"

  ```
  //Copy the files to the workspace
  File.Copy(_filePath, _testWorkSpacePath, true);
  // Add the files to Pending Changes
  _workSpace.PendAdd(_testWorkSpacePath);
  // Get the conflicts
  var conflitcs =_workSpace.QueryConflicts(new string[] { _workSpaceFilePath }, true);
  // Resolve the conflitcs
  foreach (Conflict conflict in conflitcs)
  {
       conflict.Resolution = Resolution.AcceptYours;
       _workSpace.ResolveConflict(conflict);
  }
  ```
- Check In

  ```
  var pending = _workSpace.GetPendingChanges();
  _workSpace.CheckIn(pending, comment);
  ```

Of course is good to wrap each step with `try` and `catch`.

Comment: I've seen something similar here and there but not all in one spot, I'll give it a try.  The old code I currently use pre-dates this so this is good.  Very much appreciated, I'll let you know how I go.

Comment: @Shayki Abramczyk which nugets did you use?

Comment: @Dom84 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client/